# python library for reading lz4/4mc compressed files

Tags: python-2.7, lz4

I have a file compressed with 4mc (https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc). Is there a any python library for reading 4mc compressed files? I know i can use the 4mc client to cat the file and modify my program to read from stdin. But was just wondering if there is any library in python to read 4mc compressed files

Comment: Or you could write a minimal wrapper around the v coded command line client. CFFI and friends could work with low overhead from your side (but I did not look into the headers). I know of no Python wrapper yet.